# How to handle error in this case? By Exceptions or boolean or something else

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create a Response class in Java which has a method

> void setResponse(String response);

Different response subclasses will have different requirements for the response. The string that is passed to the function is received from the user.

What is the correct way of handling a wrong response?

1. Should the function throw an exception like IllegalResponseException
2. Should the function be declared like

   > boolean setResponse(String response, String errorMsg)

and return false if the response is wrong and set the error message to the appropriate value

Edit:
I want to design the UI so that I keep prompting the user for a response until a correct one is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends somewhat on what you want the program to do when incorrect response is set.

If it's a 100% critical thing and the program should never proceed in such a case, throw an exception.

If it needs to be handled correctly by the caller and continue execution of the program, you can do either one, but I personally prefer #2. Why?

A great discussion of exceptions for error handling is [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254.html) - it does not directly address exceptions vs. return codes but a very clear list of downsides of criticisms of checked exceptions applies to this discussion as well (again, this is assuming the error you're handling is not a super-critical one which should cause program termination, in which case an unchecked exception is proper).

Comment: Using number 2, how can I check what reason caused the error. Should I set the return value as a String and code it so that a blank String means that the set function returned no errors?

Comment: @TP - you can do that. Depends on whether you need the reason for display to the user (a string would be perfect) or for programmatic reasons (e.g. a limited-value return type would be needed to determine what the program should do in case of an error based on what the reason is)

Comment: I would want to display the string to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Reserve exceptions for exceptional circumstances.

If you *expect* errors, your code should handle them as a matter of course, not throw and catch exceptions all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is out of the question since `String` in Java is immutable. If you think that you can do `errorMsg = "Wrong response!"` and have that be useful, then you need to step back right now and do some reading on what it means for `String` to be immutable, and what it means that Java passes all references by value.

For the first option, there is an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) that is often used for this purpose, so you can use that instead of your own custom exception class. It `extends RuntimeException`, meaning it's an *unchecked* exception.

Comment: I forgot about the whole immutable Strings thing in Java. I was thinking in terms of C++ and passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how a `String` can have a wrong value, especially one passed to a setter function. As such, you should probably use an exception and maybe throw it when the [wrong] string is used, not set.

It is also probably not the setter's responsibility to generate an error message string. I would consider returning more compact error information (i.e. a boolean or an enumeration, or even a class if the error should contain a lot of details) and expand on it in another class.

Comment: A response, in my case, needs to be comma seperated for some subclasses, or needs to be certain words for some subclasses so there can be errors in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Only use exception for error case which should not happen because the caller have (or could have) the sufficient knowledge to avoid it. In your case, the validity of a response seems to be hidden in your subclass implementation, with no way for the caller to know the "right" answer. Is not necessarily a problem (the response could be a password for instance), but you should return an error code instead of throwing an exception.